# what's the difference between '/etc/aliases' and /etc/postfix/aliases'

Tags: postfix

In my system I've noticed that there are these two files, coming from different packages:

1. `/etc/aliases` --> `netcfg-11.5-27.1.noarch`
2. `/etc/postfix/aliases` --> `postfix-2.11.6-19.1.x86_64`

I've also noticed that in my 'postfix' configuration, namely `/etc/postfix/main.cf` there's this line pointing to (1), instead of (2).

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

Question: is this by default like this? It doesn't make sense to me, I would expect that postfix should use postfix's file and not netcfgs.

Comment: Can you tell the OS of the server?

Comment: The OS of the server is OpenSUSE

Comment: I'm using CentOS and I've noticed that when I change the (1) file, postfix can forward the email to the emails inside of the aliases, when I use the (2) file (which was created by me after I installed postfix, it didn't come from that package) it just ignores the aliases in that file.

Answer (score 7):

From [postfix man page:](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html)

> On some systems the alias database is not in
>   /etc/aliases. To find out the location for your system,
>   execute the command "postconf alias_maps".

The `/etc/postfix/aliases` probably is a stub file to be used on system lacking `/etc/aliases`. Anyway, as you discovered, your `alias_map` points to `/etc/aliases`, so you can safely ignore the other file.

Comment: What if we want to use the postfix file instead of the netcfg file? Also I'm confused about the point of using aliases with postfix. When I do something like `user: user, user1` the main alias which is user has to be an existing user. So then, what's the purpose of the aliases then? I thought aliases worked as alias labels where if you do `users: user, user1` it will get delivered to user and user1 but users doesn't have to exist.

Comment: Please use `/etc/aliases`, it is the standard file location for such a thing. Regarding to standard aliases, they are alternative names for existing users. Emails and aliases for non-existent system users are called `virtual users` and `virtual aliases`. Give a look at postfix man page for more information.

Comment: I know you are recommending to use /etc/aliases over /etc/postfix/aliases but if in the case that I would like to use the postfix file, how can I change it to it? Thanks for your response.

Comment: You change the `alias_map` directive inside `main.cf`, pointing it to the file of choice.

Comment: ok thanks, and what should I use after I change that directive, `newaliases ` or `postalias`?

Comment: You can use `postalias /etc/postfix/aliases` (or whatever file do you want)

Comment: So you use `postalias` for postfix aliases and `newaliases` for /etc/aliases only? or I can use `newaliases` for both?

Comment: They do the same thing, albeit with a different syntax. Anyway, you should **really read the relative man pages**, as the answers to your questions are readly available on postfix documentation.

Comment: You can also redirect mail using aliases...perhaps sending mail bound for root to a distribution group that relays the messages to all the sysadmins.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/aliases` is a more generic file, which would be used by some other mailservers as well. In postfix you can use this or configure any other file, as you already found in the configuration. When postfix uses afile via `hash:` map, you should always run postmap `/path/to/file` after changing something. In case of the aliases file there is the `newaliases` command to do it.